# Sam deploy User is not authorized to perform: iam:XXXXRolePolicy despite AdministratorAccess, However works with GUI Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sam, aws-sam-cli

I have a template.yaml that worked before and doesn't work now, I am 90% sure that I didn't modify anything.

The error message looks like below:

> API: iam:PutRolePolicy User:                                                                                                                arn:aws:iam::xxxxxoooo:user/ray is not                                                                                                               authorized to perform: iam:PutRolePolicy on                                                                                                                             resource: role cron-                                                                                                                       LambdaExecutionRole-PTYXWCAQZPOE with an                                                                                                                           explicit deny in an identity-based policy

I have done the steps below and still fail:

1. Add AdministratorAccess for user ray, the same error message is still there
2. Cut out template.yaml from 5 services to only 1, and it still fails
3. Add inline policies on the role, referenced from [link](https://medium.com/@jun711.g/authorizing-aws-cloudformation-role-to-perform-iam-createrole-on-resources-2928e5ca5be7)
4. `brew install aws-sam-cli` again

However, If I push the Retry button on Cloudformation GUI, it would work.

How can I solve this properly?

##### Another failed example

template.yaml

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09' 
Resources:
  BatchTaskFargateRole:
    DeletionPolicy: Retain
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Action:
              - sts:AssumeRole
            Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/CloudWatchLogsFullAccess
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
```

result

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ResourceStatus                                 ResourceType                                   LogicalResourceId                              ResourceStatusReason
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CREATE_IN_PROGRESS                             AWS::IAM::Role                                 BatchTaskFargateRole                           -
CREATE_IN_PROGRESS                             AWS::IAM::Role                                 BatchTaskFargateRole                           Did not have IAM permissions to process tags
                                                                                                                                             on AWS::IAM::Role resource.
CREATE_FAILED                                  AWS::IAM::Role                                 BatchTaskFargateRole                           API: iam:CreateRole User:
                                                                                                                                             arn:aws:iam::xxxxx00000:user/ray is not
                                                                                                                                             authorized to perform: iam:CreateRole on
                                                                                                                                             resource:
                                                                                                                                             arn:aws:iam::xxxxx00000:role/
                                                                                                                                             BatchTaskFargateRole-1SCd8L0GR
                                                                                                                                             with an explicit deny in an identity-based
                                                                                                                                             policy
CREATE_FAILED                                  AWS::CloudFormation::Stack                     test-cloudformation-stack                      The following resource(s) failed to create:
                                                                                                                                             [BatchTaskFargateRole].
```

Comment: are you the owner of your account? is your account in an organization? Looks like pther one might restrict something to your account / IAM user.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
Yes, I am the owner of my account, and I have tried to give myself AdministratorAccess and got the same error message

Comment: Turn out that I can't even succeed with sam hello world deployment..

Comment: Try to delete the stack and deploy again. With administration permission, it should work

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
Sadly, I have done that steps a couple of times

Answer (score 0):

Delete the stack, change inline policy of Cloudformation role to

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iam:*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::*:role/*"
    }
  ]
}
```

then try to deploy again.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
I add a role with this inline policy and AdministratorAccess and still fail
It turns out that I have to solve this [bug](https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/issues/4109) first

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I cannot succeed with `aws s3api list-buckets`(Access Denied)
I tried to create a new access key and it still doesn't work
It seems the user is totally broken
Finally, I created a new user and everything is back to normal

Thanks for the [guide here](https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/issues/4109)